# Simultaneously insert data into same table with PHP (laravel)

Tags: php, database, insert, laravel

I'm not sure if this is even possible but what the heck :) I have two URL, both trying to insert different data into the same table. Example

We have table "food" and two URL with functionality that insert into FOOD table some values

```
http://example.com/insert_food_1
http://example.com/insert_food_2
```

When loading both URLs in the same time, every one of them waits for the other one to finish first and afterwards inserts into the DB the specific values.

I know this is called multithreading or something... but i'm not sure if this can be done with PHP (or Laravel).

Any help would be much appreciated. My code looks like so ...

```php
$postToInsert = Post::create(
 array(
      'service_id' => 1, 
                'custom_id' => $post->body->items[0]->id, 
                'url' => $post->body->items[0]->share_url,
                'title' => $post->body->items[0]->title,
                'title_tags' => $tags,
                'media_type' => $mediaType,
                'image_url' => $imageURL,
                'video_url' => $videoURL
            ));

$postToInsert->save();
```

Comment: What type of database are you using? If MySQL, what storage engine does the database table use?

Comment: how much data is being inserted into the tables?  the delay shouldn't be a big problem for small inserts.. what else is going on in those pages?

Comment: If using MySQL, you can use MySQL Workbench to administer the server (if you have access) and see if the MySQL is what's taking so long. This should help you pinpoint the blocking... I've never had problems with Laravel blocking, though.. maybe just a large query?

Comment: I'm using mysql with the default engine (don't have my server on) and i'm using it on local host. I have a sleep of 2 seconds between each insert, but it seems that laravel is locking the table or something?

@msturdy around 150 inserts

I think the problem is somehow related to Laravel..

Comment: Why are you sleeping between the inserts?  Can you post some code for us to look at?

Comment: I've updated my question. (sorry for the bad formatting).

Comment: @Oceanvibe Don't be sorry just learn to format it properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of fix it. Opening them in separate browsers or php them via CURL from terminal solves the problem.

Thanks for all the help